# Consolidating RDBMS-specific tags to one on functionality?

Tags: discussion

In my question,

> [Does the SQL Standard mention trigger events on DDL (ALTER, CREATE, DROP)?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/222686/263909)

I address the fact that many databases are addressing this need with ad-hoc functionality. Do we need one tag for each database for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No, we don't

I may have actually created [event-trigger](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/event-trigger), which is the PostgreSQL name of this functionality. But I'll go on the record saying "DDL Trigger" isn't a shabby name.

While `ALTER EXTENSION` is neither really DDL nor DML and it's covered by an Event Trigger it would seem that this is such a small thing it makes sense to merge them.

I don't even care which one we get the synonym will auto-correct to the other and that's fine.

Comment: I have added a synonym [tag:event-trigger] -> [tag:ddl-trigger]. Did I understand your point correctly? it is easy to undo if not.

Comment: @PaulWhite that works for me.